# Android new build system (gradle) and aspectj

Tags: java, android, gradle

In Google IO the new build system gradle is announced to replace ant. 
My project is using aspectj and I would like to use it in my project. 
I couldn't figure out some variables to get it working. I don't find android.* output classpath there. Anyone can help?

Here is my current build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'
sourceCompatibility = 1.6

configurations {
    ajc
} 

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', includes: ['*.jar'])
    ajc files('build-tools/aspectjtools.jar', 'libs/aspectjrt.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "17"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('test')
    }
}

gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    compileJava.doLast {
        tasks.compileAspectJ.execute()
    }
    println 'lalalalala'
}

task compileAspectJ {

    ant.taskdef(resource: "org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties",
        classpath: configurations.ajc.asPath)
    ant.iajc(source: sourceCompatibility, target: sourceCompatibility,
        destDir: "?????????????????????",
        classpath: "????????????????????????????") {

        sourceroots{
            android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each {
                pathelement(location: it.absolutePath)
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

This is the old ant code that works very well:
http://code.google.com/p/anymemo/source/browse/custom_rules.xml

Edit:

Updated the build.gradle according to the first answer.However I the iajc does not seem to recognize all the libraries and complain the classes in the libraries not found

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
sourceCompatibility = 1.6
targetCompatibility = 1.6

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}

configurations {
    ajc
    aspects
    ajInpath
}

ext.aspectjVersion = '1.7.3'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    ajc "org.aspectj:aspectjtools:${aspectjVersion}"
    compile "org.aspectj:aspectjrt:${aspectjVersion}"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    variant.javaCompile.doLast {
        def androidSdk = android.adbExe.parent + "/../platforms/" + android.compileSdkVersion + "/android.jar"
    println 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA: ' + androidSdk

        def iajcClasspath = configurations.compile.asPath + ":" + androidSdk
        configurations.compile.dependencies.each { dep ->
            if(dep.hasProperty("dependencyProject")) {
                iajcClasspath += ":" + dep.dependencyProject.buildDir + "/bundles/release/classes.jar"
            }
        }
    println 'BBBBBBBBBBBBBB : ' + iajcClasspath 

        ant.taskdef( resource:"org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties", classpath: configurations.ajc.asPath)
        ant.iajc (
                source:sourceCompatibility,
                target:targetCompatibility,
                destDir:"${project.buildDir}/classes/${variant.dirName}",
                maxmem:"512m",
                fork:"true",
                aspectPath:configurations.aspects.asPath,
                inpath:configurations.ajInpath.asPath,
                sourceRootCopyFilter:"**/.svn/*,**/*.java",
                classpath:iajcClasspath
        ){
            sourceroots{
                android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each{
                    pathelement(location:it.absolutePath)
                }
                pathelement(location:"${project.buildDir}/source/r/${variant.dirName}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
1 [error] The method onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu) of type FingerPaint must override or impl[3780/18642]
rtype method
[ant:iajc] public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
[ant:iajc]                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ant:iajc] /home/liberty/mp/android/AnyMemo/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.java:21
2 [error] The method onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu) is undefined for the type GraphicsActivity
[ant:iajc] super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
[ant:iajc]       ^^^^^^^^^^^
[ant:iajc] /home/liberty/mp/android/AnyMemo/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.java:21
7 [error] The method onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) of type FingerPaint must override or implement a
 supertype method
[ant:iajc] public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
[ant:iajc]                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ant:iajc] /home/liberty/mp/android/AnyMemo/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.java:22
8 [error] The constructor ColorPickerDialog(FingerPaint, FingerPaint, int) is undefined
[ant:iajc] new ColorPickerDialog(this, this, mPaint.getColor()).show();
[ant:iajc] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ant:iajc] /home/liberty/mp/android/AnyMemo/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.java:25
4 [error] The method onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) is undefined for the type GraphicsActivity
[ant:iajc] return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
[ant:iajc]              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ant:iajc] /home/liberty/mp/android/AnyMemo/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.java:25
8 [error] The method getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context) in the type PreferenceManager is not applic
able for the arguments (FingerPaint)
[ant:iajc] SharedPreferences shre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
[ant:iajc]
```

EDIT:
This the final build.gradle file that works for my project:
https://code.google.com/p/anymemo/source/browse/build.gradle?spec=svnf85aaa4b2d78c62876d0e1f6c3e28252bf03f820&r=f85aaa4b2d78c62876d0e1f6c3e28252bf03f820

Comment: For your new error, I tried reproducing it by adding a jar library, but it's working fine for me.

Comment: I guess the error is not related to the library itself, since iajc seems to find your GraphicsActivity, but it could be a wrong sdk path: all your errors are either related to methods from activity that can't be found in GraphicsActivity or to GraphicsActivity that is not recognized as an activity in constructors.

Did you check the androidSdk var? Mine is pointing to somewhere in "/home/aegar/android-sdk/platforms" where I only have android-18.

Comment: It is the AAR dependency issue. The AAR can not be used as jar. You handled dependencyProject but, if you specify the     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0', the classes.jar is in exploded-bundle, all jars in this directory needs to be added to the classpath.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out that the AAR can not be used as a jar library in my code. If you are using dependencies like this

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
```

You need to find the jar file and add to the classpath. The following code will do it.

```
tree = fileTree(dir: "${project.buildDir}/exploded-bundles", include: '**/classes.jar')
tree.each { jarFile ->
    iajcClasspath += ":" + jarFile
}
```

So the whole section would be:

```
variant.javaCompile.doLast {
    // Find the android.jar and add to iajc classpath
    def androidSdk = android.adbExe.parent + "/../platforms/" + android.compileSdkVersion + "/android.jar"
    println 'Android SDK android.jar path: ' + androidSdk

    def iajcClasspath = androidSdk + ":" + configurations.compile.asPath
    configurations.compile.dependencies.each { dep ->
        if(dep.hasProperty("dependencyProject")) {
            iajcClasspath += ":" + dep.dependencyProject.buildDir + "/bundles/release/classes.jar"
        }
    }

    // handle aar dependencies pulled in by gradle (Android support library and etc)
    tree = fileTree(dir: "${project.buildDir}/exploded-bundles", include: '**/classes.jar')
    tree.each { jarFile ->
        iajcClasspath += ":" + jarFile
    }
        println 'Classpath for iajc: ' + iajcClasspath

        ant.taskdef( resource:"org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties", classpath: configurations.ajc.asPath)
```

For the full example please see the build.gradle for AnyMemo project here:
https://code.google.com/p/anymemo/source/browse/build.gradle?spec=svnf85aaa4b2d78c62876d0e1f6c3e28252bf03f820&r=f85aaa4b2d78c62876d0e1f6c3e28252bf03f820

Comment: Note: Using tools 19 I think they may have changed the location. I needed to use 'exploded-aar' instead of 'exploded-bundles' from the above example.

Comment: withoutclass, Yes they changed name. https://code.google.com/p/anymemo/source/browse/build.gradle?spec=svnf85aaa4b2d78c62876d0e1f6c3e28252bf03f820&r=f85aaa4b2d78c62876d0e1f6c3e28252bf03f820 has the change.

Comment: THANK YOU! I missed this post and struggle with aegar answer before I gave up and look here. This answer need more upvotes.

Answer (score 15):

I also wanted to use aspectj with gradle and Android Studio, and I finally got it working, but I still have some hand-written paths that I'd like to replace with more generic gradle options.

**Edit:** I replaced every hard-coded absolute paths with gradle based alternatives, so this solution does not depend any more on a given platform or user name. However, it still uses relative paths that could change from an IDE to an other or in further releases of Android Studio.
Also, I'm not really satisfied with the way I find the android.jar.

I first load aspectj:

```
configurations {
ajc
aspects
ajInpath
}

ext.aspectjVersion = '1.7.3'

dependencies {
    compile project(":LibTest")

    ajc "org.aspectj:aspectjtools:${aspectjVersion}"
    compile "org.aspectj:aspectjrt:${aspectjVersion}"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
}
```

And I then add a task that will run after the JavaCompile task of the current variant:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    variant.javaCompile.doLast {
        def androidSdk = android.adbExe.parent + "/../platforms/" + android.compileSdkVersion + "/android.jar"

        def iajcClasspath = configurations.compile.asPath + ";" + androidSdk
        configurations.compile.dependencies.each { dep ->
            if(dep.hasProperty("dependencyProject")) {
                iajcClasspath += ":" + dep.dependencyProject.buildDir + "/bundles/release/classes.jar"
            }
        }

        ant.taskdef( resource:"org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties", classpath: configurations.ajc.asPath)
        ant.iajc (
                source:sourceCompatibility,
                target:targetCompatibility,
                destDir:"${project.buildDir}/classes/${variant.dirName}",
                maxmem:"512m",
                fork:"true",
                aspectPath:configurations.aspects.asPath,
                inpath:configurations.ajInpath.asPath,
                sourceRootCopyFilter:"**/.svn/*,**/*.java",
                classpath:iajcClasspath
        ){
            sourceroots{
                android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each{
                    pathelement(location:it.absolutePath)
                }
                pathelement(location:"${project.buildDir}/source/r/${variant.dirName}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Wherever I use `${variant.dirName}`, it will be replaced by either "debug" or "release" according to the current build configuration.

Adding android.jar to the classpath is required to compile Android specific classes, and the line `pathelement(location:"${project.buildDir}/source/r/${variant.dirName}")` is require to use classes from the auto-generated R.java file.

**Edit:** The iterations over the project dependencies to build iajcClasspath let you use classes from your libraries projects. `configurations.compile.asPath` already contains a reference to your apklib (aar file), which is actually a zip containing both the jar and the resources of the library. Iajc doesn't recognize these files as it, but there is a bundle directory containing the classes.jar for your library under the build directory. I use a relative path with "release" hard-coded in it, because the library has a different variant than the main project in my situation, so I can't use `${variant.dirName}` here.

Here is the complete build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}

configurations {
    ajc
    aspects
    ajInpath
}

ext.aspectjVersion = '1.7.3'

dependencies {
    compile project(":LibTest")

    ajc "org.aspectj:aspectjtools:${aspectjVersion}"
    compile "org.aspectj:aspectjrt:${aspectjVersion}"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    variant.javaCompile.doLast {
        def androidSdk = android.adbExe.parent + "/../platforms/" + android.compileSdkVersion + "/android.jar"

        def iajcClasspath = configurations.compile.asPath + ";" + androidSdk
        configurations.compile.dependencies.each { dep ->
            if(dep.hasProperty("dependencyProject")) {
                iajcClasspath += ":" + dep.dependencyProject.buildDir + "/bundles/release/classes.jar"
            }
        }

        ant.taskdef( resource:"org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties", classpath: configurations.ajc.asPath)
        ant.iajc (
                source:sourceCompatibility,
                target:targetCompatibility,
                destDir:"${project.buildDir}/classes/${variant.dirName}",
                maxmem:"512m",
                fork:"true",
                aspectPath:configurations.aspects.asPath,
                inpath:configurations.ajInpath.asPath,
                sourceRootCopyFilter:"**/.svn/*,**/*.java",
                classpath:iajcClasspath
        ){
            sourceroots{
                android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each{
                    pathelement(location:it.absolutePath)
                }
                pathelement(location:"${project.buildDir}/source/r/${variant.dirName}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  My only issue now is aspectj not finding classes from a library project,  any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: I have the same issue regarding the use of libraries, I thought it would be enough to add the library project to iajc classpath, but it seems that is is already in it: `println configurations.compile.asPath` shows a path starting with `/home/aegar/AndroidStudioProjects/AopProject/LibTest/build/libs/LibTest.aar` in my case, so I think the problem is that iajc doesn't recognize the aar libraries as it.

Comment: @withoutclass: iajc now recognizes my libraries, I updated the answer. I hope it will work for you too.

Comment: I'd like to note that for me, I needed to set source and target to "1.6" in order to get this to build.  Seems like it was defaulting to some other java version and was causing me issues.

Comment: I still have trouble get it working. It looks seems to have trouble finding classes. Even though iajcClasspath seems to be very valid (All jars are just there). I got error:[ant:iajc]  The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type SpreadsheetListScreen
[ant:iajc] FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
[ant:iajc]    [ant:iajc] ...
/UploadGoogleDriveScreen.java:94 [error] The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(UploadGoogleDriveScreen)
 is undefined

Comment: Edited the question about the details of the failure.

Comment: Thank you finally get things working. See my answer below. aegar's answer is just one step from working but it takes me months to find out :)

Comment: Was able to build with minor changes to this script. I am trying to use monkeytalk for test automation, which requires using aspectj compiler instead of java compiler, is there a way to override javaCompile task with iajc?

Answer (score 4):

Although previous answers scripts works for most of the situations, they doesn't cover some of the problems of using Android with AspectJ and Gradle.

My test was to create a library project that should be used by anyone via mavenCentral or by me as a reference library project, and a test application project. The library project is the one that has all the aspects and the application test was trying to use those aspects.
Giving this as a context, the resulting project structure was:

```
HEAD-Gradle
---LibraryProject
-------SomeAspects
---TestApplication
-------Uses-SomeAspects
```

The solutions I found that make it work are:

1- For library projects you must use

```
libraryVariants.all { variant ->
```

instead of

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
```

2- The build dir changed for 19.+ build tools of Android, so as it is suggested in one comment (thanks to "WithoutClass"), you have to use the exploded-aar dir instead of exploded-bundles dir in the tree variable definition.
From:

```
def tree = fileTree(dir: "${project.buildDir}/exploded-bundles", include: '**/classes.jar')
```

To:

```
def tree = fileTree(dir: "${project.buildDir}/exploded-aar", include: '**/classes.jar')
```

3- The final problem I faced when making the integration was that if you have a library project, aspects defined on it were not found on the child project. To solve this you have to add the classes.jar of your custom library to the aspectJ compiler configuration. You can achieve this by adding to the dependencies:

```
aspects project(":YourLibraryProject")
```

and it is also needed to make some changes in the script provided in the final of this post.

Right now the best script I can imagine that gives full support for aspectj using even library projects is:

For dependencies:

```
configurations {
    ajc
    aspects
    ajInpath
}

//Version of aspectj
def aspectjVersion = '1.8.+'
// The dependencies for this project
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //Your dependencies to a custom library project
    compile project(":YourLibraryProject")
    aspects project(":YourLibraryProject")
    //Aspectj dependencies
    ajc "org.aspectj:aspectjtools:${aspectjVersion}"
    compile "org.aspectj:aspectjrt:${aspectjVersion}"
}
```

The compiler running script

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

variant.javaCompile.doLast {
    // Find the android.jar and add to iajc classpath
    def androidSdk = android.adbExe.parent + "/../platforms/" + android.compileSdkVersion + "/android.jar"

    def iajcClasspath = androidSdk + ":" + configurations.compile.asPath
    //This line and the fordward assignations allow the aspects support in the child project from the library project
    def customAspectsPath = configurations.aspects.asPath
    configurations.compile.dependencies.each { dep ->
        if(dep.hasProperty("dependencyProject")) {
            iajcClasspath += ":" + dep.dependencyProject.buildDir + "/bundles/${variant.buildType.name}/classes.jar"
            customAspectsPath += ":" + dep.dependencyProject.buildDir + "/bundles/${variant.buildType.name}/classes.jar"
        }
    }

    // handle aar dependencies pulled in by gradle (Android support library and etc)

    def tree = fileTree(dir: "${project.buildDir}/exploded-aar", include: '**/classes.jar')
    tree.each { jarFile ->
        iajcClasspath += ":" + jarFile
    }

    ant.taskdef( resource:"org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties", classpath: configurations.ajc.asPath)
    ant.iajc (
            source:sourceCompatibility,
            target:targetCompatibility,
            destDir:"${project.buildDir}/classes/${variant.dirName}",
            maxmem:"512m",
            fork:"true",
            aspectPath:customAspectsPath,
            inpath:configurations.ajInpath.asPath,
            sourceRootCopyFilter:"**/.svn/*,**/*.java",
            classpath:iajcClasspath
    ){
        sourceroots{
            android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each{
                pathelement(location:it.absolutePath)
            }
            pathelement(location:"${project.buildDir}/source/r/${variant.dirName}")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Remember that if you want to run AspectJ on a library-child project, you must have also this script on the build.gradle of the library.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of using Android Studio 0.8 or above, it seems that using gradle 0.12.+ is necessary.

In gradle 0.12.+, exploded aar are extracted in the build folder, not in the exploded-aar folder.

Therefore, in order to handle aar dependencies, you must use this code:

```
tree = fileTree(dir: "${project.buildDir}", include: '**/classes.jar')
tree.each { jarFile ->
    iajcClasspath += ":" + jarFile
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another easier way to set things up is using the android aspectj plugin which is better maintained.
https://github.com/uPhyca/gradle-android-aspectj-plugin