# Gradle sync failed with gradle version 2.2.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

I have build one app with android-studio.But when I am trying to compile project I am getting error

```
Error:No such property: bootClasspath for class: com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin
```

I am not getting what's wrong with me.
Here is my build.gradle file.If anything more needed please ask

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.uphyca.gradle:gradle-android-aspectj-plugin:0.9.8'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-aspectj'
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testApplicationId "com.xxxx.app.activity.tests"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        monkeytalk.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
        monkeytalk {
            applicationIdSuffix ".monkey"
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
sourceSets {
    unitTest {
        java.srcDir file('src/androidTest/java')
      //  resources.srcDir file('src/androidTest/resources')
    }
}
configurations {
    unitTestCompile.extendsFrom runtime
    unitTestRuntime.extendsFrom unitTestCompile
}

// add the unitTest task
task unitTest(type:Test) {
    description = "run unit tests"
    testClassesDir = project.sourceSets.unitTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = project.sourceSets.unitTest.runtimeClasspath
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile 'com.google.android:android-test:2.1_r1'
    compile 'junit:junit:3.8.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libraries', include: ['*.jar'])
    monkeytalkCompile fileTree(dir: 'monkey-libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
    compile files('libraries/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
}
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like a problem with aspectj. Perhaps this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245402/android-new-build-system-gradle-and-aspectj

Comment: @Joel couldn't solve it.Thanks for trying.

Comment: i donot think that android `buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"` will work with gradle 1.2.2. Current android-studio 1.0 uses gradle 2.2.1. have you tried to compile using gradle 2.2.1 ?

Comment: @k3b  Did you mean  
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'

Comment: No, i dont mean classpath. i refer to the name of this posting: `Gradle sync failed with gradle version 1.1.2`. what do you get if you execute on the commandline `gradlew --version` ? can you load and build the project with `gradlew --gui` in the project-root dir?

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake.It's 2.2.1.